# Using a PreMatching filter to change uri path

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

In short, I have a Jersey REST service in a jar that I need to deploy in my webapp using mapping that differs from that which is defined in the annotations of the service.  In the service, I have `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` and `@Path("/foo")`.  However, incoming requests will be of the form: `http://example.com/delegate/rest/foo` (note that *delegate* is NOT a context path, rather it is mapped to servlet in the ROOT webapp that loads session information and proxies the request to my webapp, which means I cannot override `@ApplicationPath` with a `servlet-mapping` as would usually be the case).  So, what I am trying to do, is this:

```
@PreMatching
@Priority( 500 )
public class DelegateRemappingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DelegateRemappingFilter.class );

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestContext ) throws IOException {
        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        // convert baseUri to http://example.com/delegate/rest
        URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
                .path( uriInfo.getPathSegments().get( 0 ).getPath() ).build();
        URI requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();

        // As expected, this will print out
        // setRequestUri("http://example.com/delegate/rest","http://example.com/delegate/rest/foo")
        LOGGER.debug( "setRequestUri(\"{}\",\"{}\")", baseUri, requestUri );
        requestContext.setRequestUri( baseUri, requestUri );
    }
}
```

However, this ends up failing to match.  Is it not possible to modify the path portion of the URI in a `@PreMatching` filter?  I thought that is what this type of filter was for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate when I find my own answer *MINUTES* after posting...  Anyway, the `baseUri` *MUST* end in a `/`.  So changing this:

```
    URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
            .path( uriInfo.getPathSegments().get( 0 ).getPath() ).build();
```

to this:

```
    URI baseUri = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
            .path( uriInfo.getPathSegments().get( 0 ).getPath() + "/" ).build();
```

did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I had opposite problem but your solution helped--I was modifying the path portion, not base uri, and path has to *start* with a "/". So I had to prepend the "/".